# Why mysql real_escape_string vsprintf does not work

Tags: php, mysql

Now I have convert my query with PDO format. But I must implement the query with old format for little next time. The code is like this:

```
function mysql_Select($sql) {
    $data=array();
    $params=func_get_args();
    $s=PreparaSQL($sql, $params);
    $res = mysql_query($s);
    if ($res && mysql_num_rows($res)){
        while( $dt = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
            $data[]=$dt;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

function PreparaSQL($sql, $array_param){
   unset($array_param[0]);
   foreach ($array_param as $k => $v){
      $array_param[$k]=mysql_real_escape_string($v);       }
  return vsprintf( str_replace("params","%s",$sql), $array_param );  
}
```

And execute the function is :

```
$data=mysql_Select('SELECT concat(id," | ",wh2) as label,Id as kode,wh2 as nama,wh2 as value FROM wh011 where wh2 like %s',$_GET['where']);
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

And output have error with `null` value. I think the trouble is in this code:

```
return vsprintf( str_replace("params","%s",$sql), $array_param );
```

I really don't know where is the error point.
Thank's for you answer.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I realize that you're converting to PDO, but I feel compelled to post that comment whenever `mysql_*` funcs are used ^

Comment: Since you're using functions, you can refactor your code naturally inside of the functions. As long as the input is placed in the same format, and the results are returned in the same format, you won't need to change any other piece of code.

Comment: @truth.. yes.. you right. with my function, i am not wonder about change technology. my code, before, use the "mysql_query();" in all query page. why i still use mysql_*?, because  i must reporting the progress code in a month. And next, i must learn to create PDO function for my crud database. thank's to orourkek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have parameter 1 and 2 the wrong way around.

Try:

> $sql = " here is my string params did you find it?\n";
>
> echo vsprintf(str_replace("params","%s",$sql), "BOO!");

Output

```
 here is my string BOO! did you find it?
```

I'd suggest just not doing the str_replace... ?

Comment: thanks. i have change my code to your response, like this: return vsprintf( str_replace("%s","params",$sql), $array_param );  but still have null return.

Comment: Ah, I think that perhaps the problem is in the "logic" here.  vsprintf needs to have the %s in there yes?  and you're passing it the %s, but replacing it with the word "params" which vsprintf fails on.  Look at my updated answer to see if that helps.

Comment: yeah... thank's so much. trying with this code :echo vsprintf(str_replace("params","%s",'SELECT concat(id," | ",wh2) as label,Id as kode,wh2 as nama,wh2 as value FROM wh011 where wh2 like %s'),'"%aaa"'); and the query string was right : SELECT concat(id," | ",wh2) as label,Id as kode,wh2 as nama,wh2 as value FROM wh011 where wh2 like "%aaa".

Answer (score 0):

You can't use mysql_real_escape_string() until a connection has been established.  You may have to write your own escape method.  See the notes section [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for more details.

Comment: i think mysql_real_escape_string has been in my connection. because if i execute with this code, the connection executed  before mysql_Select function and the function returning value.this is the code : $data=mysql_Select('SELECT concat(id," | ",wh2) as label,Id as kode,wh2 as nama,wh2 as value FROM wh011'); and this is the result : [{"label":"1 | Celullar","kode":"1","nama":"Celullar","value":"Celullar"}]